# Graphql: which is better to use variables or headers

Tags: reactjs, graphql, nestjs

I'm writing back on nestjs/mongodb and front on reactjs. And use graphql between them. I had some needed info in headers, or I passed it through variables in query.

Is it cheaper to pass it through variables or through context?

When user logs in, I'm setting headers: filialIds

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {     
    const token = localStorage.getItem(${localStorageAppPrefix}.token`);

    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        filialIds: `${localStorage.getItem(`${localStorageAppPrefix}.filialIds`) ?? ''}`,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
      },
    };

});

export const client = new ApolloClient({ 
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink), 
    cache: new InMemoryCache(), 
});`
```

When user query smth, I'm checking his filialIds and role in Guard
`

```
@Injectable() export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate { 
    constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
      const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
      const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<UserRoles[]>(
        ROLES_KEY,
        [context.getHandler(), context.getClass()],
      );
    
      if (!requiredRoles) {
        return true;
      }
    
    const queryFilialIds =
        safeJSONParse(ctx.getContext()?.req?.headers?.filialids ?? '') ?? [];
    const { roles, filialIds } = ctx.getContext()?.req?.user ?? {};
    
    const hasRequiredFilials = filialIds?.every(
        (filialId) => queryFilialIds.indexOf(filialId) !== -1,
    );
    
    const hasRequiredRoles = requiredRoles.some(
        (role) => roles?.indexOf(role) !== -1,
    );
    
    return hasRequiredRoles || hasRequiredFilials;
    }
}`
```

But I also need the access to filialIds and role in service, like here:

```
async getCount(context): Promise<number> {
  const filialIds =
    JSON.parse(context?.req?.headers?.filialids ?? '') ?? [];
  return this.userModel.countDocuments({ filialIds: { $in: filialIds } });
}
```

So the question is: Should I use context or pass it from graphql query like here:

```
const { data } = useQuery(GET_USER, {
  variables: { filialIds: filialIds ?? [] },
  skip: !filialIds?.length,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem. I presume that `filialIds` is some sort of *affiliation id*?

1. If the affiliation id is an attribute of the *user* then you could include it in your JWT token or just append it to the user object whenever you check the JWT. Furthermore if it's a user attribute then there's no need to send it from the client to server at all.
2. If the affiliation id is an attribute of the *site* in a multi-tenant situation then a header makes perfect sense - not however that one site could potentially spoof another
3. If most or many of your resolvers need this variable then having it as a query variable seems tedious.